# Is it possible to have a joomla powered website within a OpenVZ container?

Tags: linux, webserver, openvz

Could someone please elaborate the steps to get a website running within a container?Suppose a website is up and running within a OpenVZ container,will the web server be accessible from  1.Host? 2.Other containers?

Comment: Get Concrete 5 O.o

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your both questions 1 & 2 are : YES & YES

Steps:

install Linux on your OpenVZ container (distribution to your liking, make sure it is a server OS not desktop to make your life easier down the road)

install Apache if necessary (some server distributions include Apache in the distribution)

install Joomla package(s)

Pretty straight forward if you ask me...

Comment: Joomla requires php to be installed on the HN.I installed it and added a file info.php with the line phpinfo() in /var/www/html.But typing my ip followed by info.php on the browser doesn't display the php manual page.

Answer (score 0):

An OpenVZ container is a full linux OS, so you can install most linux software into it. The networking can be configured in a few different ways.  If you give your CT a private IP, you will need to setup destination NAT to route from the hostnode to it.